# php namespace Class not found

Tags: php, namespaces

Version_DefaultComponentForm.php

```
namespace ComponentManagement\Form;
class Version_DefaultComponentForm extends VersionForm {
    public function __construct($name = null) {
```

ComponentManagementController.php

```
namespace ComponentManagement\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use ComponentManagement\Form;
use ComponentManagement\Model\Component;

    class ComponentManagementController extends AbstractActionController {
        protected $albumTable;
        public function indexAction() {
            $componentForm = new Form\ComponentForm();
            $versionForm = new Form\VersionForm();
            $version_DefaultComponentForm = new Form\Version_DefaultComponentForm();
```

I got this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'ComponentManagement\Form\Version_DefaultComponentForm' not found in D:\WEB\xampp\htdocs_zend\module\ComponentManagement\src\ComponentManagement\Controller\ComponentManagementController.php on line 15

Can not find any bug by myself...Could anyone tell me why? using php 5.4.7 with zend 2.0

No idea why，but it works correctly now.

```
namespace ComponentManagement\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use ComponentManagement\Form;
use ComponentManagement\Model\Component;

class ComponentManagementController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        $componentForm = new Form\ComponentForm();
        $versionForm = new Form\VersionForm();

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $component = new Component();
            $componentForm->setInputFilter($component->getInputFilter());
            $componentForm->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($componentForm->isValid()) {

            }
        }
        return array('forms' => array(
                'ComponentForm' => $componentForm,
                'VersionForm' => $versionForm,
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Wild guess: you didn't `include_once("Version_DefaultComponentForm.php")`?

Comment: Still need include that file after using namespace in php?

Comment: I do not know, some how it works now, without include. There is a ComponentManagement\Model\Component Class works fine all the way. no idea why...

Comment: @TKL, I think it may be because your original class name contained an underscore, pretty sure the StandardAutoloader will transform that to a `/`

Comment: "**Class and Interface naming**
All classes, interfaces, and abstracts must begin with an uppercase
character.  They may contain additional capital letters and
underscores.  **Any underscores in class names will be converted to the
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR when attempting to auto-load.**"

http://news.php.net/php.standards/2

Answer (score 1):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html

> Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader is designed as a PSR-0-compliant
>   autoloader. It assumes a 1:1 mapping of the namespace+classname to the
>   filesystem, wherein namespace separators and underscores are
>   translated to directory separators.
>   :P

Comment: I'm sure the PSR-0-compliance people thought to themselves "Yeah, sure, nobody *ever* uses underscores in file names!"