# PHP classes in namespaces not found

Tags: php, autoload

I tried to load a utility class to my main class with a namespace but everytime I try to run it it seems to not be working as in not finding the class. The error I got is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPapa\assets\php\Classes\Verification.php
    [1] => C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPapa\assets\php\autoload.php
)
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Verification\VerificationUtility" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPapa\assets\php\Classes\Verification.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPapa\assets\php\Classes\Verification.php on line 7

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Verification\VerificationUtility" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPapa\assets\php\Classes\Verification.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPapa\assets\php\Classes\Verification.php on line 7
```

The first array is for me to check what files is included using the `get_included_file()` function and I have loaded my `autoload.php` file which loads the rest of my utility classes. This is my code that throws the error above:

```php
<?php
namespace Verification;

include dirname(__DIR__) . "\\autoload.php";
use Verification\VerificationUtility as utility;

echo (new utility())->test();
print_r(get_included_files());
```

and my `autoload.php` file:

```php
<?php
foreach (glob("Classes/*Utility.php") as $filename)
{
    include_once $filename;
}

print_r(get_included_files());
```

I tried searching online but I cannot find a solution. I tried [php namespace Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208619/php-namespace-class-not-found) or [PHP namespace confusion, class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741382/php-namespace-confusion-class-not-found)

I made changes and double checked my code, I am including the utility class from `autoload.php` as this is the output of `autoload.php`

```
$ php autoload.php
Array
(
    [0] => C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPapa\assets\php\autoload.php
    [1] => C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPapa\assets\php\Classes\VerificationUtility.php
)
```

Is my autoloading somehow wrong? Thanks for any help in advance.

**Edit:**
I tried to include the file only without the autoload and it is working just fine. However I would like to use the autoloader because if my classes start expanding it would be a pain to include every single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the pattern in `glob` is relative to the working directory, you may use a determined path.

```
glob(dirname(__DIR__) . "/Classes/*Utility.php")
```